# How far does a joist need to overhang past a supporting wall?

Tags: walls, joists

I'm looking to remove a very small partition wall that is brick. Its basically only the side of a small cupboard containing the boiler.

I’ve looked above it and it doesn’t appear to be supporting anything aside from two joists that run over it. These joists also rest on the supporting wall approx. 70cm away too.

All other joists in the floor are similar but do not have this small partition wall running underneath them (as it is only a cupboard in the corner as mentioned).

The one thing i notice is that the two joists on the cupboard wall only over hang the supporting wall by approx. 2cm (by this i mean they run across the supporting wall and have 2cm excess at the other side). Is this okay?

I wanted to check as the other joists have about 10-15cm overhang compared to this 2cm.

Comment: Pictures will help.  If I understand, these joists have a shorter over hang than others?  Possible they are shorter to make space for something(chimney?)  Most joists just need to sit on a supporting wall, usually overhangs are a design feature.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged. Image uploads are quite intuitive in the post editor (basically the same as any other site on the internet).

Answer (score 5):

None. In fact, it only needs to *bear* a few cm. There's no requirement whatsoever for overhang. You can even butt-join joists in the center of a typical wall. Minimum bearing is often the same as a single board thickness.